# How to get the same DNN model in Bigquery and Keras

Tags: deep-learning, google-bigquery, tf.keras

I created a new DNN model using BQ with the following hyperparameters

```
OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE='DNN_REGRESSOR',
 ACTIVATION_FN = 'relu',
BATCH_SIZE = 200,
EARLY_STOP = False,
HIDDEN_UNITS = [200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200],
INPUT_LABEL_COLS = ['users'],
LEARN_RATE=0.001
```

And I tried to get the same model using Python, to do so I used the `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor`
and [default params that BQ used](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-dnn-models)  **but there are many differences.**
(for the categorial variable I used OneHotEncoder)

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns=feats,
    hidden_units=[200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200],
     optimizer=lambda: tf.optimizers.Adam(
            # learning_rate=tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
            learning_rate=0.001,
            # global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(),# couldn't find in v2 
            # decay_steps=200,
            # decay_rate=0.96))
        ))
```

**The question is how can I create identical model to the one I created in BQ through python???**

Comment: It's unclear if the comments (# and --) are uncommented when you run these or if they're not. If they are active when running then at the very least the learning rates are different - the default is 0.01 in BQ.

Comment: I removed the comments, there are a lot of changes between Bigquery and Keras, BQ is fully managed, you don't need to deal to change categorial features and also if I used the same hyperparameters, my BQ works well while Keras is not converging.

Comment: Have you tried to [export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/exporting-models#console) Bigquery ML model to Tensorflow [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) format? Does it convey any difference?